Can I set a default image for an image field in a webforms form?
Is there a way to set a default image file to an webforms image file field type so that the image shows up instead of a link to it for authenticated users? I know there is a way to have the image show up for authenticated users in webforms, but this only seems to happen after an image is chosen by the form's user.
This is what I have that allows the image to be set into the default value as a link rather than a displayed image in my hook_form_alter function:
$form['elements']['myimage']['#default_value'] = [$image->id()];

